# Primefaces Googlemap Marker Infowindow : Disable vertical scroll bar

Tags: jsf, primefaces, vertical-scrolling, primefaces-gmap

I am using Primefaces google map component. I have some markers and info windows for those markers. The problem I am facing is it is showing the vertical scroll bar. But I don't need the vertical scroll bar. How can I hide the vertical scrollbar?

---

**Update**: in the first screenshot you can see that the vertical scroll is not needed as all data vertically is already visible.

[image]

In the second screenshot you can see the horizontal scrollbar, we have to scroll down. I just want that the vertical scrollbar disappears and only the horizontal scrollbar remains, which should be always visible.

[image]

Comment: it would help us a lot to understand your problem if you attach a screenshot of the problematic component.

Comment: hmmm no answers yet.... I am still interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `min-height` to your infoWindow class element.

That will resolve the issue if your infoWindows are all the same size.

If not, add this line of jQuery to your click function for the infoWindow:

```
//remove overflow scrollbars
$('#myDiv').parent().css('overflow','');
```

Comment: got my nuts cracked while modifying javascript for primefaces

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width and height of the container that holds the InfoWindow's contents the scroll bar will disappear.